# How to return a boolean indicating wether an element is clickable, using an asynchronous method (Jasmine - Protractor - Typescript)?

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, promise, jasmine, protractor

I want to confirm that a visible webelement is not clickable. Since I need to validate this as a jasmine-expectation (that can produce a test report) I need a boolean; this is what I have:

```
public static async isElementClickable(element: ElementFinder): boolean{
   try {
       await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element), 50);
       return true;
   }catch (e) {
       return false;
   }
}
```

I would call that method like this:

```
expect(isElementClickable(myPage.buttonThatIsNotClickable)).toBe(false);
```

The method above doesn’t work, because it is asynchronous  and therefore can only return a promise.

How do I have to change this, or what do I need to add to get a boolean? Can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `async` in your it callbacks.

```
it('should return false', async () => {
  const result = await isElementClickable(myPage.buttonThatIsNotClickable);
  expect(result).toBe(false);
});

// Alternative way
it('should return false', (done) => {
  isElementClickable(myPage.buttonThatIsNotClickable).then(result => {
    expect(result).toBe(false);
    done();
  });
});
```

But your function should return a Promise and not a boolean. I am surprised TypeScript allows that. It should be like so:

```
public static async isElementClickable(element: ElementFinder): Promise<boolean>{
   try {
       await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element), 50);
       return Promise.resolve(true);
   }catch (e) {
       return Promise.resolve(false);
   }
}
```

Comment: used the second snippet - it works as intended. I cannot upvote your answer yet, but will come back when I've reached 15 reputation.

Comment: In the top example for `async (done)` You do not need the `done` and the `done();` since the test is already async.